# Find the constants in a 2D flow (incompressible, newtonian)

Tags: fluid-dynamics

$$u_1=x_1^2x_2$$
$$u_2=A+Bx_1x_2^2$$
$$p=cosx_1$$

The fluid is an incompressible Newtonian fluid $\implies$ $u_i,i=0$ and $tor_ij=-p\delta_ij+\mu u_ij$

Fluid bounded by a stationary rigid plate at $x_2=0$

Find A and B

So far, I have bounded by rigid plate at $x_2=0$  $\implies$ $u(x_2=0)=0$ so $A=0$
I'm trying to formulate $tor_ij$ to find B but getting nowhere. Any ideas?

I then have to define the traction the fluid exerts onto the plate...

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is viscous fluid with viscosity $\mu$. You are right about constant $A$ by using the "no-slip" condition on the boundary $x_2=0$. To get $B$, you may just use the incompressibility condition, i.e.

$$
\nabla \cdot \vec u=\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}=0
$$

The equation should require that $B=-1$.

To get the traction the fluid exerts on the plate, you should be introduced the concept of stress tensor:

$$
\sigma_{ij}=-p\delta_{ij}+2\mu e_{ij}
$$
where
$$
e_{ij}=\frac12 \left( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} \right)
$$

which is the symmetric *strain rate tensor*.

Having calculated the $2 \times 2$ matrix $\sigma_{ij}$, and remembering that the force per unit area (stress) exerted on the fluid by a surface with unit normal $\vec n$ pointing out of the fluid is $\sigma \times \vec n$, you should then be able to calculate the force, depending on which side it is.

Hope this helps.